# 'Unable to get the window handle for the 'AxVLCPlugin2' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vlc, libvlc

I have problem with reopening the certain window form with embedded VLC player, in my Windows app that I am working on.
The problem is next, I embedded VLC player with "VLC ActiveX Plugin and IE Web Plugin v2" and everything works fine on that form while its open, I can insert, copy, delete, move video files and all that filestream, path.combine actions and play it on that VLC, but as soon as I close that form with "this.Close()", and reopen it again from the main menu form, error appears saying: 'Unable to get the window handle for the 'AxVLCPlugin2' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported...

the error occurs in that particular VLC form where is embedded in "form.Designer.cs" at this line:

((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.VLCprozor)).EndInit();

I have tested the form by interacting with other elements on the form without triggering any line of code that involves VLC plugin, then closing and reopening the form again, and it works perfectly fine without any error or exception thrown.
But soon as I interact with some buttons that contains some VLC line of codes and involve that plugin or even start playing the video through embedded VLC, after that if I close the form and try to reopen again, this exception appears in my face :)

I have some beginners experience and practice in C#, but in this case, I see that I don't have technical abilities to even understand how to fix this, I tried to dispose(), to endinit(), but doesn't show results or any effect...

If anybody can step up and show me the way, or just guide me or advice me where to look and explain me what can possibly be wrong.

Thx in advance in effort...

Comment: this might be of help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9c36e5d3-a75c-4760-9070-5dbaf188992b/unable-to-get-the-window-handle-for-the-axnlevel2-control-windowless-activex-controls-are-not

Comment: Anyway i found out, i put "this.ActiveControl.Controls.Clear()", that was the action i needed.

Comment: I checked that earlier yesterday, I literally checked a lot of those topics on that subject and nothing really helped me or at least I didn't find the way out, but now it works, thank you for your good will Luc! :)

Comment: pardon, the correct line is "ActiveForm.Controls.Clear();"

Comment: AXVLC has been deprecated for a while, please consider migrating to LibVLCSharp if you want a supported alternative.